# MacBook Pro early 2008 model wont boot into Linux install

Tags: boot, lubuntu, kubuntu, live-usb, macbook-pro

I'm a beginner using Linux and have used Mint, Kubuntu, Ubuntu, Manjaro, ElementaryOS and Fedora on another machine (Macbook Air 2013).

I have an old MacBook Pro I wish to revive, but I can't seem to get it to boot and install on any distro except Lubuntu (specifically 18.04 alternative). I can get it to install but then it just sits in black screen forever I've tried waiting and many posts on here but I can't get anything to work. I get the USBs to boot and bring up a menu for install or try Linux but no matter what I do I can't progress to any further steps except with as the aforementioned Lubuntu. Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the hashes of the downloaded ISO?

Comment: I have, everything is fine on that side

Comment: Did you check the hashes of the installed media? That's a little bit more difficult, but it checks for copy errors while checking the ISO itself only checks for download errors.

Comment: Also done, I'm currently check to see if a noefi install will work

Comment: How much free memory you have? Alternative is unique in that it's a non-graphical installer and so memory usage is really low.

Comment: im pretty sure theres enough  2gb

Comment: When you get to the point where you can't progress further, can you open a virtual terminal with e.g. Ctrl-Alt-F2?

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks @wxl for all the help I have figured it out i just need to boot into the installer with noacpi nosplash nomodeset, and have rEFInd preinstalled fixed all the problems i was have getting into the live session and graphical installer.
So far I've tested and had success with mint, kubuntu, ubuntu, and manjaro.
Thanks Wolve_Saint